# Setting Data to Angular material data table from Node API and its sorting case sensitive order so how to prevent it?

Tags: sorting, mui-datatable

I am setting data from node API to angular material datable and added a sort header to a specific column but the problem is sorting I mean when I perform a sort on a specific column it does not give the perfect result

e.g
my data is as follows

No.  column-1  column-2

1. abcd ff    sfsfk
2. Adcd sd    gfdfd
3. Asdjf      sdffg
4. Bddf       sdfsf
5. bssfsd     sfere
6. amdfd      sdfsf
7. Bsdf       sdfs

When I am performing a sort operation on column 1 then the result i am getting is as follows

No.  column-1  column-2

1. Adcd sd    gfdfd
2. Asdjf      sdffg
3. Bddf       sdfsf
4. Bsdf       sdfs
5. amdfd      sdfsf
6. abcd ff    sfsfk
7. bssfsd     sfere

But I want exactly as follow (Case insensitive)

No.  column-1  column-2

1. abcd ff    sfsfk
2. Adcd sd    gfdfd
3. amdfd      sdfsf
4. Asdjf      sdffg
5. Bddf       sdfsf
6. Bsdf       sdfs
7. bssfsd     sfere

Please let me know how to archive this result.
Note: From API I am getting perfact result as I want but when I set that API data in an angular MUI table and when I sort it performs case-sensitive sorting so I want to perform case-insensitive sorting when the user performs sorting operation on a particular column

Comment: Add code that displays table and does sorting

Comment: hi @antokhio yes i can add the code but its very long code because we use redux to fetch and dispatch data so its not possible to post all code here if give any hint then its most helpfull

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.